# How to set ringing mode for specific contact

Tags: android

I am developing an application which will allow certain contact to ring even if the phone is in silent mode . So how i can set ringing mode for specific contact.

Comment: I want to do for specific contact

Answer (score 1):

look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/579466/Android-Set-Ringer-Silent). This way you will get to know how to set it to ringing mode.

Comment: thnks but i want it for specific contact

Comment: in that case you could create a service that detects a call coming, and then check if its the number for which you want to change the mode, use the contacts content provider to crosscheck the presence of the number and change the ringing mode. You could get tutorials on contacts provider, and also services if you google a little more